# Data-Binding with Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am having a problem not being able to bind my data and then display it using cshtml. I have tried different methods of making observable arrays and I am thinking, my main problem comes from trying to utilize my supposedly "bounded-data"...The following is my cshtml(c#-html) code, and then my js code.

```
 <!--*****Unfinished*****-->
                    <td>
                        <label class="element-label">Continuous (Vibratory) Acceleration</label>
                        <select class="form-control device-family-selector" , data-bind="options: changeAuxFlange.availableVForces, optionsText: 'forceName', value: changeAuxFlange.selectedForces, optionCaption: 'Choose a force...'"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input style="width:50px; text-align:right;" , data-bind="text: changeAuxFlange.selectedForces" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="element-label">Maximum (Shock) Acceleration</label>
                        <select class="form-control device-family-selector" , data-bind="options: changeAuxFlange.availableSForces, optionsText: 'forceName', value: changeAuxFlange.selectedForces, optionCaption: 'Choose a force...'"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input style="width:50px; text-align:right;" , data-bind="value: changeAuxFlange.selectedForces" />
                    </td>
                    <!--**********-->
```

view model:

```
"use strict";
function ViewModel()
{
    // it would make more sense with the current setup to make the ViewModel be the Application, but I have set it up like this in case some day it is desired that this tool creates multiple applications in one session
    this.application = ko.observable(new Application('New Application', this));
    this.requestSearchMode = ko.observable(false);
}

function Application(name, parentViewModel)
{....
this.sections =
    {
        gForceSection: initGforceSection(this),
        pumpSection: initPumpSection(this),
        calcLoadsSection: initCalcLoadsSection(this)
    }....
}

    function initGforceSection(application)
{
    var data = ko.observableArray();

    var gForceSection = new Section('G-Forces', data, application);


    var self = this;
    var Force = function (name, value) {
        this.forceName = name;
        this.forceValue = value;
    };
    var vibForce = {
        availableVForces: ko.observableArray([
            { vForce: "Skid steer loader", value: 4 },
            { vForce: "Trencher (rubber tires)", value: 3 },
            { vForce: "Asphalt paver", value: 2 },
            { vForce: "Windrower", value: 2 },
            { vForce: "Aerial lift", value: 1.5 },
            { vForce: "Turf care vehicle", value: 1.5 },
            { vForce: "Vibratory roller", value: 6 }
        ]),
        selectedForces: ko.observable()
    };
    var shockForce = {
        availableSForces: ko.observableArray([
            { sForce: "Skid steer loader", value: 10 },
            { sForce: "Trencher (rubber tires)", value: 8 },
            { sForce: "Asphalt paver", value: 6 },
            { sForce: "Windrower", value: 5 },
            { sForce: "Aerial lift", value: 4 },
            { sForce: "Turf care vehicle", value: 4 },
            { sForce: "Vibratory roller", value: 10 }
        ]),
        selectedForces: ko.observable()
    };


    gForceSection.families = ko.observableArray();
    productData.getPumpFamilies(function (data) {
        gForceSection.families(data);
        addPump(application);
    });

    gForceSection.tbxNumberofPumps = ko.computed(function () { return gForceSection.data().length });

    return gForceSection;
}
//CREATE VIEWMODEL
var viewModel = new ViewModel;

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
/******/
```

Comment: Don't see any call to apply the bindings.

Comment: Yea, sorry I do have it. I've included to pieces of information you'll may need to help me.

Comment: Don't see where changeAuxFlange is even associated with your view model or even instantiated.

Comment: The items in your `data-bind` attributes appear to have no bearing on what they're bound to (the properties on `Application`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewModels is a series of nested objects which makes references quite complicated. I can see you're trying to logically structure the data but it makes it difficult to help. Knockout has a [context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) for binding which starts with the bound viewmodel. You can change the context for an element/section using the `with` binding.

Otherwise you have to give Knockout a full path, e.g. `data-bind="value: app.gforcesection.someitem.someProperty` - this can be cause errors if an item in the path is undefined.

I've removed a lot of the structure to make it a working sample to try to help:
http://jsfiddle.net/Quango/3y9qhnv9/

The new viewModel is now a 'flat' object with all the properties on it directly. I wasn't sure why you bound the input boxes to the force so I amended those to bind to the value property of each one. Hope this helps you in the right direction.

Comment: yes very helpful, thank you. Just if I would want to use all the layers i would do something like....data-bind="options: viewModel.application().initGforceSection(application).availableVForces, ...etc?

Comment: Yes, you _could_ but it's best avoided if possible. If possible use a `with` bindin if you can. http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html has some useful tips as well.